# can't permanently delete automatic MAC-based inet6 address

Tags: ipv6, rhel6

Although I never explicitly configured ipv6 on my rhel servers and only have static ipv4 configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, an automatic ipv6 address based on MAC address keeps being added.

Now there's a need to reuse this automatic address as a static address on another machine.

Tried to delete it with:

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 del 2a00:1120:0:1002:215:5dff:fe55:ac11/64
```

it reappears a few minutes later.

Is it possible to blacklist certain address from being automatically configured?

Comment: 2a00:1120::/48 belongs to Reksoft Ltd. and is marked for internal use. You using any of their products or services?

Comment: @Brian is it important for solving my problem?

Comment: Let the other machine use its own address. Don't try to duplicate addresses like this. If you _think_ you need to do this, you need to _clearly explain why_ (because you don't need to do this, should not even be attempting it, and explaining why will allow for finding an actual solution).